# Static Alternative in PHP for <b>Parse error</b>: syntax error, unexpected T_STATIC in <b>

Tags: php, singleton, static-methods, php4

I was testing my PHP application on localhost with Xamppp and everything was just fine, but when I exported it to a real server, it does not work anymore. I found out that it is because my server does not support late static binding. 
My server has version **5.2.17**.

I get this error.

```
<b>Parse error</b>:  syntax error, unexpected T_STATIC in <b>/home/storage/f/9d/09/meuplacar/public_html/filme/work/class_lib.php</b> on line <b>555</b><br />
```

I just use the `static` keyword in a Util class I built. What would you suggest for me to change this kind of methods:

**Util**

```
class Util
{
    private static $initialized = false;
        private static function initialize()
        {
            if (self::$initialized)
                    return;
            self::$initialized = true;
        }

    public static function getHoursAndMinutesFromTime($time) {
        self::initialize();
        $pieces = explode (":", $time);
        $output = "";
        $output = $pieces[0] . ":" . $pieces[1];
        return $output;
    }
}
```

And for a Unique Facade Instance

**Singleton**

```
abstract class Singleton {

    protected static $_instance = NULL;

    /**
     * Prevent direct object creation
     */
    final private function  __construct() {
    }

    /**
     * Prevent object cloning
     */
    final private function  __clone() {
    }

    /**
     * Returns new or existing Singleton instance
     * @return Singleton
     */
    final public static function getInstance(){
        if(null !== static::$_instance){
            return static::$_instance;
        }
        static::$_instance = new static();
        return static::$_instance;
    }

}

class Facade extends Singleton  {

    public function retrieveAllWorkdays()
    {
        $array = DB::selectAllWorkdays();
        return Util::constructWorkdaysArray($array);
    }
```

Comment: I've just updated the question. Version 5.2.17

Answer (score 0):

Late static bindings only are available in php 5.3.0 and later: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php

Comment: Yeah. I know, but I want suggestions for an alternative.